# How do I get the output using while loop?

Tags: python

I am not getting the output I am expecting. The output should be the sequence of values of less than 6. Is something wrong in the syntax? I think it has very simple error!! I am not getting it.

Write a while loop to display the values of the Rating of an album playlist stored in the list `PlayListRatings`. If the score is less than 6, exit the loop. The list PlayListRatings is given by: `PlayListRatings = [10, 9.5, 10, 8, 7.5, 5, 10, 10]`

```
PlayListRatings=[10,9.5,10,8,7.5,5,20,10]
rating=0
i=0
while rating<6:
   rating=PlayListRatings[i]
   i=i+1
   print(rating)

>>output 10
```

Comment: If you exit the loop, further list items can't be checked if they are less than 6.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to use a for loop:

```
for item in PlayListRatings:
    if item < 6:
        break
    print(item)
```

If you must use a while loop:

```
index = 0
while index < len(PlayListRatings) and PlayListRatings[index] > 6:
    print(PlayListRatings[index])
    index += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You define `I=0` but then use `i=i+1`.  Python is case sensitive, so you need to use the same casing (i.e. set `i=0` instead of `I=0`).

**If the score is less than 6, exit the loop.**

This means that your while condition is incorrect.  It should be `while rating >=6`.

I would highly recommend reviewing conditional statements, looping, and basic python syntax.

Answer (score 0):

While loops are generally used when you don't know when the loop is expected to end, for loops are better when you know the loop will end. 
In your example you are looping through a list, you are better using a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```py
PlayListRatings=[10,9.5,10,8,7.5,5,20,10]
rating=0
i=0

while i != len(PlayListRatings):
    rating = PlayListRatings[i];
    if rating < 6: print(rating);
    i=i+1;
```

I know that `while` loop logic needs some time to get accustomed to. Here is what you need to think of when building a while loop:

- > *When building a while loop*: Logic that governs *while* loop needs to be negative.

```py
## don't run this , it is an infinite loop
iDontWantThis = false; # starting argument 
# it is always false, so the loop will go forever
while iDontWantThis == false: 
   print("I want this");
```

So when iterating over a list of some kind, the logic that governs *when you exit the loop*, must not be the same logic that you wish to implement inside the loop. That is main difference between `while` and `for` loops.

**In your case** , your main logic was to print out any element in list that was smaller than 6, so in while loop you need to have logic that is either:
     1. For `rating` that is greater than 6
     2. For `i` index that is smaller than list length
     3. Infinite loop with `break` points inside while loop.

- > *Python is case sensitive* : which means that `I` and `i` aren't the same variable. But this can happen even to experienced programmers.
- > *Beginner while loop building* : when you start learning about `while` loops. The best course of action is to start with infinite loops, and then implement breaks where you need them. When your code works, then you optimise it so you don't have too much lines and it gets faster.